# How to fix Stack not adding lines right?

Tags: c#, .net

Right now with the code below, when i try to call the method, `Console.WriteLine(ss[0])` returns `System.IO.ReadLinesIterator` and `Console.WriteLine(ss[1])` returns this error: `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'` here's my code

```
static Stack<string> Loaded = new Stack<string>();  


public static void loadFile()
    {
        string ii = File.ReadLines(@"D:\test.txt").ToString();
        Loaded.Push(ii);
    }  


        public static void AddValues()
    {
        while (combos.Count > 0)
        {
            string line = Loaded.Pop();
            string[] ss = line.Split(':');
            Console.WriteLine(ss[0] + "55.65" + ss[1]); // error here because it isn't making the array right or something, not sure
        }
    }
```

an example of what the test.txt file looks like would be
Value1:Value2
Value6:Value4
What i need is for it to take each line and split giving me `Value155.65Value2`

Comment: Remove .ToString() and use ReadAllText instead

Comment: You need something like `foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(@"D:\test.txt")) { Loaded.Push(line);}`

Comment: @Evk i tried this and kept getting error could not convert char to string although i even tried with .ToString();

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen this works, but it now outputs like this  
`Value2 \n Value6`  i used \n to represent newline because it doesn't work in comments

Comment: You're reading the whole file as one string; you need to think through what you want to be done here. Unfortunately, this is not a good fit for a Q&A site such as Stack Overflow because every answer we give you will spark new questions.

Comment: Try simply do `Loaded = new Stack<string>(File.ReadLines(@"D:\test.txt"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply doing `Loaded = new Stack<string>(File.ReadLines(@"D:\test.txt"));`
thanks to @khoroshevj

Answer (score 1):

`File.ReadLines` returns `IEnumerable<string>` so the problem is that you assign `IEnumerable<string>` to `string`.

what you need is `File.ReadAllText`.This method just returns string.

So, instead of

```
string ii = File.ReadLines(@"D:\test.txt").ToString();
```

use

```
string ii = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.txt");
```